# php array convert to string

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => 21 
        [SLOTID] => 21
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => 4 
        [SLOTID] => 4 
    ) 
)
```

I want to create a new string from this array like:`21,4`.

I'm very new in PHP.

Comment: Use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = $arr[0][0] . ',' . $arr[1][0];
```

Comment: @AwladLiton What do you want to do when you have more values? Create more strings, or modify that one string to be longer, or is this good enough?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the standard way to do this

implode(",",$arr)